# How to add the same methods to Fragment and DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, oop

I want to add the same instance methods to Fragment class and DialogFragment class.
DialogFragment extends Fragment so I want add a method to Fragment class.
But I can't because Fragment class is given from Android.

I created MyFragment class and MyDialogFragment class and implemented the same methods.
But I'm looking for smarter way than this.

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: That depends on your use case (it could very well be that the best way to do it *doesn't* involve adding those instance methods)

Comment: You can put the methods in another Class that both your Fragment & DialogFragment could create and use.